# Glusterfs fstab

Tags: server, mount, fstab

Currently I have 2 bricks that are replicated.  I'm trying to mount a client to gluster.  The only way I can get it to work is if I do this in the fstab:

hostname:volume  /test  glusterfs  defaults,_netdev 0 0

when I do this

glusterfs:volume /test glusterfs   defaults,_netdev 0 0

it fails to mount.

How do I configure the glusterfs-fuse client so I don't have to put one of the hostnames of the volume in.    I'm assuming by me putting the hostname for one of the nodes (if that node was to fail) It wouldn't mount to the other node.

It seems like it might be a dns issue